# After nsq.run() my python script is not executing block of code in "pynsq" package

Tags: python, django, tornado, nsq, pynsq

[image: code screenshot]

I am trying to use "pynsq" package (message broker service) to my django project. but when i run the Asynchronous consumer request using nsq.Reader() class by using nsq.run() command it takes my main thread and my code after this command is not executing .

for eg:- as shown in the picture after nsq.run() i am trying to print("hello") but the print function is not calling when i run this .py script .i have tried my best to find solution for this.

is it possible to use this package in my django project ? becauese when i run this script after nsq.run() my code of block is not executing.

please can anyone suggest me the solution for this to use this package in my django project.

Answer (score 0):

`nsq.run()` function starts an event loop in the background. Basically, it's a `while`-loop which runs forever. So any code written after this line won't be executed.

> please can anyone suggest me the solution for this to use this package in my django project.

You can run `nsq` in a separate process from your django process, then use something like [Celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/) to pass messages between the two.